# Dynamic Scope Variable Names in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a lot of fields/models where the logic placed on them will be the same in the controller except for the scope variable name. I'd like to avoid huge IF statements if possible by appending numbers to the scope variable names if possible. I can do this in jquery etc but how to do this in Angular?

For example I have $scope.search1 and $scope.search2. I'd much rather it be $scope.search + id. Is this possible?

In the controller where I have

```
$scope.getresults= function() {
    if ($scope.search1) {
        $http.jsonp('http://api.com/', {
        params: {
            query: $scope.search1
        }
    if ($scope.search2) {
        $http.jsonp('http://api.com/', {
        params: {
            query: $scope.search2
        }}}
```

I'd much rather be able to do:

```
$scope.getresults= function(param) {

        $http.jsonp('http://api.com/', {
        params: {
            query: $scope.search + param
        }}
```

but that obviously does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not clear why the function argument won't work. Putting a wrapper around `$http` or other ajax calls is done all the time

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.  You show a sample that wouldn't be practical, and a sample that you say "obviously does not work", but it's really not obvious at all why it wouldn't work.  What is it you are really trying to accomplish here? can you add more context?

Comment: also, does this have anything to do with the previous question that you asked?  Even in that other question, it wasn't really obvious what you are trying to do, having a search box for every item that you render that essentially does the same thing doesn't really make sense.

Comment: also why would you have so many individual scope variables and not a model object or array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties inside object in Javscript can be accessed in two ways, Dot Notation (object.key) or bracket notation object['key'], in the latter way, you can use expressions or dynamic variable names like object[expression], since $scope is an javascript Object, it would be great to use bracket notation to access the scope with the dynamic value the you are passing like this :

```
$scope.getresults= function(param) {

        $http.jsonp('http://api.com/', {
        params: {
            query: $scope['search' + param]
        }}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use object notation.

```
$scope['search' + param]
```